# How to limit the character in textarea if we using 'jQuery InlineEdit'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, inline-editing

I am using `jquery.inlineedit.js` for inline edit and i need to control the maximum length of texts inside the textarea. I tried with someother common jquery script to limit, but i can't make it.

Below is the link what i tried so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/LNBRU/4

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `max-length` property for that

```
<textarea maxlength="20"></textarea>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNBRU/7/)

Answer (score 0):

1. add an event handler for the changing of the input's content
2. if it exceeds the character limit, truncate the string